# Springsource tool suite skipping codes

Tags: spring, debugging, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a very weird problem. When I try to debug a code, sts totally ignores the code. 
Below is my very simple code and I wondered why the values did not change, when I debugged, the lines from `{` to `client.employmentKindOfWork ="asdasd"` are not executed. It skips all and jumped right into client.save().

```
Client client = Client.FindById(caseInstance.clientIdClient);
if (client!=null) {
  client.clientMailAddr1="sdfsdfsf"
  client.isDelete = true
  client.employmentKindOfWork ="asdasd"
  client.save()
}
```

I tried the following steps:

1. cleaning thru wizard command
2. by clicking project then clean.
3. Build the project few times.
4. open and close STS.
5. Create new workspace then Imported the project again.
6. Adding this line in preferences?Java>je edit and default vm
   -XX:+UseParallelGC
7. Refreshing the project by right click and refresh
8. recompile thru command wizard

All of which did not work!!!

Pls. suggest anything I haven't tried that might fix this aside from updating because all my team mates have the same version I have and they are not having this prob.

Comment: some questions: Does this happen only when stepping through in the debugger, or also when the debugger is not being used?  Are you sure that `client` really is not null?  What happens when you remove the if statement?  What happens when you add sys.out.println statements after each call to change `client`?  Are the values of client being updated?  Make sure that your Java compiler preferences are set to include line numbers in the class files.

Comment: it happens on both the debugger and it when it is not being used. Yes, I am sure it is not null because it gets in the If statement and jumps to client.save(). No, the values are not beng updated that is why I set it to debug mode to see what is happening and there it is, the lines before save are ignored. The orig code does not have IF and nothing happens, it still skips the lines. When you say" Make sure that your Java compiler preferences are set to include line numbers in the class files." where exactly can I see that? Sorry I am new to java and sts. thanks.

Comment: Actually I saw the "Java compiler preferences are set to include line numbers in the class files". Yes, it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not running the code that you think you are.  Add some system.out.println statements and see if they are being reached.  My guess is that they are not.  Most likely, you are compiling your class files to one location, but running a stale version of them from another location.

I am assuming that this is a maven project.  Make sure that in your java build path (Ctrl-I on the project), that the output folder is set to target/classes and target/test-classes.