# Groovy debugger out of sync

Tags: eclipse, debugging, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am having a difficulty while attempting to debug some code in grails. It is difficult to put into text, so I have posted a screencast showing exactly what the problem is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwl2vGpXEYU). In short, while I am debugging the debugger starts jumping from place to place and not following the program logic I have in place. The only other similar question I have found is a year old, had no solution, and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784329/springsource-tool-suite-skipping-codes).

The best guess I have so far is that the debugger is displaying the text I have typed in, but is actually executing an older version of the class file which it has cached somewhere. Therefore, I tried:

- cleaning the project
- manually deleting all of the class files from the target folder and from the target-eclipse folder
- Searching my entire hdd for additional files with similar names
- removing my project from the workspace and re-adding it
- closing and reopening the IDE
- grails refresh-dependencies
- Importing the project into a new IDE (I was using GGTS, I switched to IntelliJ)

None of those solutions had any effect. I realized that the issue was in a .groovy file, and I was writing almost pure Java, so I deleted the .groovy file, and re-created the class in a .java file. That solved my problem. Unfortunately I am having the problem again, and this time it is in a controller that heavily relies on the grails framework, so that solution is not an option. Other than also being in a .groovy file, another similarity is that the code breaks on an if statement.

My next steps:

- Verify that the application is not executing the code I see by using print functions to monitor actual execution flow.
- comment out the entire function and re-add functionality one line at a time to see if I can see what breaks it.
- Delete the .groovy file, and re-create it as another .groovy file.

Any help is appreciated, and since I can't find any answers online I will continue to update this question as I learn more.

Comment: Update:

I verified that the code that is executing is not the same as the code which is being shown to execute. Details <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2tDUlTGoJ4">here</a>. Specifically, the places where the debugger is stopping at the end of code blocks is just an illusion.

For now I am working around this by ignoring the anomalous jumps in the debugger. I have been able to code well enough this way, but it is far from ideal.

Comment: Update: I noticed another, presumably related, issue with the Grails Debugger. I was trying to work around the problem by adding a variable and then printing off its value at different points in the program execution. What I found was that when I cleaned and recompiled the program, the line declaring the variable was not being executed, but the line calling the variable to print its value was being executed. Clearly this threw an exception because the debugger believed that the variable had not been declared.

Comment: I attempted to resolve all of the above issues by upgrading from grails 1.3.7 to grails 2.2.0. The upgrade was not going well, and the application is rather small at this point, so I created a new project in grails 2.2.0, created empty classes with the correct names, and then pasted in the logic from my old code. The effect was to wipe out all of the previously existing trouble areas and debugger bugs, but then the same issue was cropping up in new project as well, just at different places in the code.

Comment: I tried many compile options for compiling Groovy scripts and then executing them, but I still have the issue you describe about the debugger being out of sync. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment on the [jira issue that you raised](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3333#comment-86273).  You have found a problem with the groovy compiler and how it calculates line numbers.  This is not a problem with executing the wrong class files or using a broken debugger.  The debugger is doing exactly what it is expected to do.  It is the compiler that is providing erroneous line number information.

The next step, as described in the issue, is to provide a simple project that recreates the bug.  I tried to do so myself, but could not.  So, please supply something that we can work with.  Then we can notify the groovy compiler team.